# Error code 410 Gone in Fetching reviews on Google Play store

Tags: google-api, google-play, review

Anyone can help me to understand what is exact meaning of error code 410 for API for fetching reviews on play store. I am unable to find any details on documentation. I am referring https://developers.google.com/android-publisher/api-ref/reviews/get